# How to make groups of five elements from the list?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, list

My GAE application receives several files in the upload (can be from 0 to N). I have there list in `files_arguments` list:

```
files_arguments = self.request.arguments()
```

I need to take first 5 elements, process them. Then take next 5 elements and process. And so on. Last group, of course, can have less than 5 elements.

What should be the code to do so? (I will not use `files_arguments` after that, so elements can be deleted from the list once processed)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the low-tech approach. It doesn't throw away the last group if it's smaller than `n`.

```
n = 5
groups = [files_arguments[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(files_arguments), n)]
```

Comment: FMc, could you please explain how it will work? Or, how I can use that - first, I need to take first 5 elements and process them (how to do it with your code?)

Comment: @LA_ The `groups` variable holds a list of lists. To process each group, you might do something like this: `for g in groups: process_group(g)`.

Answer (score 3):

As it [says in the documentation for `zip`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip),

> The left-to-right evaluation order of the iterables is guaranteed. This makes possible an idiom for clustering a data series into n-length groups using `zip(*[iter(s)]*n)`.

So the full groups are `zip(*[iter(files_arguments)]*5)` and the final short group (if any) is `files_arguments[-len(files_arguments)%5:]`.

[FMc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890065/how-to-make-groups-of-five-elements-from-the-list/6890244#6890244) is simpler and easier to understand in this case, but I think the `zip` idiom for grouping is entertaining so it deserves a mention here.

Comment: Using `itertools.izip_longest` will eliminate the issue where partial groups are discarded.

Answer (score 1):

```
def pickN( mylist, N=5 ):
    if ( len(mylistl) < N) return mylist
    a = mylist[0:N]
    for _ in range(N): mylist.pop(0)
    return a
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want an iterator which returns full, padded lists:

```
def group(a, n=5, default=None):
  a = iter(a)
  while True: 
     yield [next(a)] + [next(a, default) for i in range(n-1)]

>>> list(group(range(8))
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, None, None]]
```